# Execute code every 1 millisecond

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I have a thread that eventually will get its data from a sensor every 1ms and does some processing which should take less than 1ms (say 0.5ms). For the moment I wish to simulate the sensor using another thread. So my goal is to have a thread that generates data every 1ms and sends it to another thread. Lets assume generating and sending times are negligible.

I tried using `this_thread::sleep_for` but it didn't work well. I got basically random sleeping time anywhere between 1ms and 15ms. I think I can use `chrono::high_resolution_clock`. But that  would require busy wait.

Any other ideas?

I can settle for an average of 1ms provided that in no case it is less than the processing time.

Comment: What platform are you working on?  Clock resolution (and programatic control over it) varies between Windows, Linux, etc.  That being said, 1 ms resolution can't usually be achieved reliably outside of real-time operating systems.

Comment: What @nephtes said. You're probably stuck with the busy wait.

Comment: No way you get 1 ms sleep on non-realtime system.

Comment: busy wait might not be good either - your time checking call might be an espensive system call on exotic system.

Comment: Well I am working on Windows and I was hoping to avoid busy wait but I see that it may not be possible.

Comment: *Well I am working on Windows*  That's the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind wasting processing power, use busy wait: spin until the millisecond elapses:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto now = start;
while (not_ready(start, now))
{
  now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
```

Comment: Will not really work on systems where getting tick count is a system call itself.

Comment: Note on older version of VS on Windows, high_resolution_clock wasn't very, erm, high resolution so you'd need to use QueryPerformanceCounter or getSystemTimeAsFiletimePrecise. This is fixed iirc in the latest version of VS.

Answer (score 0):

One millisecond is way below the normal scheduling threshold of most operating systems. Don't expect to be able to get two processes or threads to interact reliably with that frequency.
On Linux, for example, the scheduler timeslice is usually 100ms by default (although it can be lower, but don't expect less than 10ms).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up a timer for 1 millisecond reload and using the interrupt vector for the timer.

On the embedded system I'm working on, we a have a 1ms timer tick ISR.  We have tweaked the hardware to get this as accurate as possible (including using oscilloscopes for measurement).

You may want to make it the highest priority interrupt or task.

The processor we use comes with several timers.  When the timer expires, it can execute code as an interrupt.

Comment: Wouldn't it require Ring0 permission?

Comment: Permission is totally dependent on the platform.  The platform I'm using uses Micrium COS-II.  There are no rings.  Just an ARM processor memory and other devices.  We don't bother with execution permissions; keeping things simple.

Comment: Ok :) interesting to now. I am so far away from embedded :)

Comment: Bah. Kids today. Why when I was a lad a high-end embedded system had an 8 bit processor, half a K of RAM--up hill, both ways--and we LIKED it!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can request a custom timer resolution with the `timeBeginPeriod()` call (see [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743626(v=vs.85).aspx)).  You'll probably still want to test to see how close it actually gets you to 1 ms, though.

Also bear in mind that even busy-wait isn't a surefire solution here.  If the CPU is under sufficient load, there's no guarantee that your program will get execution time within any given 1-millisecond slice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to sleep for intervals less than 1ms? Have you tried usleep() (unistd.h) or nanosleep() (time.h)? There might be some jitter due to scheduling imprecisions --- if this is not acceptable, you need to resort to a spin loop.

Comment: From what I now understand the scheduler cannot work in such short interval. Isn't it so?

Comment: I don't see why not, unless the machine is very loaded or you need extremely precise timing. If you need extremely precise timing then you can only spin; yielding the processor puts you at the mercy of the scheduler. But it doesn't sound like you really have such a strict requirement. If usleep()/microsleep() never could not offer roughly what they advertise because of the scheduler, I don't think they'd be as widespread as they are.